# Vim as a note taking platform: Jump to tag in vertically split windows

Tags: vim, tags

In the past, I have used Vim as a note taking platform by creating an index.txt file with a list of tags using the Vim help file format and then creating a bunch of text files that have the normal `*Help_Tag*` link syntax so that using `CTRL-]` on a tag in the index.txt file will jump to the respective tag in an arbitrary notes text file. You need to do `:helptags dir` to generate the tags for the directory (where dir is the path to the notes directory).

[image]

What I am looking for is a simple way to be on the left split window and open the tag under the cursor in the right split window. Something like `CTRL-W v` but for tag jumping and using the already open vertical split window.

The problem is if you do `CTRL-]` it will open the tag in the left pane and if you do `CTRL-W CTRL-]` it creates a horizontally split window in the left pane.

There must be a way to do this that I'm overlooking.

Comment: I can't tell. Is this a questions about *using* vim, or about writing scripts for it? If the former it should be migrated to Super User.

Comment: I guess it could be either. I'm thinking that a script is needed but maybe someone knows of a way to do it natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiset would be an autocommand local mapping

```
au FileType index.txt nnoremap <buffer> <cr> 
    \ :vert belowright split 
    \ |tag <c-r><c-w>
    \ |vert resize 130<cr>
```

Note I use <kbd>return</kbd>

Comment: Using the help command requires having the notes files in my .vim/doc folder. Plus it would open a new pane to the left. This can be avoided with `:rightb vert help test` but the width of the split is 50/50. Is there a way to specify the width of the vertically split pane?

Comment: I'd like to use the 'tag' command instead of 'help' but this does get the job done. Do you know how I can make the tag command open in the right window? When I try it now it will open to the left.

Comment: you just need to split|tag instead. I've updated the map. note I've used <c-r><c-w> instead of <cword> to mimick actual key motions. not sure if this makes a difference

Answer (score 2):

map <A-]> :vsp<CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>")) " Open the definition in a new vsplit

Comment: Now how do I get the split to open to the right of my current buffer?

Comment: `set splitright` in your .vimrc to have all vertical splits open to the right @Amjith

Answer (score 1):

Try this mapping:

```
nmap <buffer> <C-]> :let word=expand("<cword>")<CR><C-W>l:exe "tag" word<CR>
```

It stores the word under the cursor in the variable `word`, then swaps the window and goes to the tag with that name.  The `<buffer>` bit makes this mapping only apply to the current buffer.

Comment: I came with up with this kind of mmap `nmap <C-\> :vsplit<CR>:let word=expand("<cword>")<CR><C-W><C-W>:exec "tag" word<CR>
` to allow <C-]> still work and use <C-\> only for the first ctag

Answer (score 0):

If you're using headings as note titles, you could use [Vim VOoM](https://github.com/vim-scripts/VOoM), which automatically outlines based on sytax and allows for easy navigation with the standard navigation keys.

Vim VOoM also works with foldmarkers, like in the example screenshot.