# Vim with split frame of buffers or file listing

Tags: vim

Similar in appearance to [Vim as a note taking platform (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269798), I would like a pane with a list of open buffers that can be used as a jump to list. This is one feature in many IDEs and other advanced editors that is missing.  Having a dozen buffers or so open becomes confusing as to which buffer is where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several Vim add-ons designed to ease buffer navigation. You can find a partial list here: [Vim Tips Wiki - Easier buffer switching](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching#Scripts).

A few of the most popular are:

- [bufexplorer](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=42)
- [minibufexpl](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159)
- [LustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890)
- [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984)

Note that some filesystem navigation add-ons, like [The NERD Tree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658), are also smart about their buffer handling. If a file is already open in an existing buffer, for example, NERD Tree will select that buffer instead of attempting to open the file again. (NERD Tree also allows you to keep the file tree open in a separate pane, which I really like.)

One last thought -- if you're using a version of gVim that supports tear-off menus, you can 
just tear off the Buffers pulldown and use it as a jump list.

Answer (score 1):

How about using tabs? `:help tabpage`

Answer (score 0):

I like minibufexpl personally; sometimes mixed with tabs to keep specific alignment.